# How to convert NSString object into Array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have below string:

```
{"list": {"array":[{"current_rate":20.0,"id":1, "name": "abc"}, 
                   {"current_rate":20.0,"id":2, "name": "xyz"}]}}
```

I want to convert above string into array like

```
[current_rate: 20.0, id: 1, name: abc]
```

I used `componentSeperatedByString:@":".`

But it gives problem when name field contain ":" string.

Is there any way to convert above string into array.

Comment: I Think It Should help you

[Stackoverflow][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955009/how-to-convert-nsmutablearray-objects-nsstring-data-into-lowercase-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you have seems valid JSON. You may want to parse it:

```
NSData *data = [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
```

Then you can get the object using the `objectForKey:` and `objectAtIndex:` methods on the appropriate classes.

Comment: @H2CO3.. Thanks for this simple answer.